# Return the Data from Column Using PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell

When I export the $dt to a CSV - it shows in 1.A of Excel = 1 and in 2.A = 2.  I need to extract the two value of the second row in column A.  First why is the count working? And why do I not get a return for the values in the last two echo commands when I know there is a value = 2 in Row#2 - Column A?

````
  $factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory('IBM.Data.DB2')
  $cstrbld = $factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder()
  $cstrbld.Database = 'mydb'
  $cstrbld.UserID = 'user'
  $cstrbld.Password = 'userpass'
  $cstrbld.Server = 'server:port#'
  $dbconn = $factory.CreateConnection()
  $dbconn.ConnectionString = $cstrbld.ConnectionString
  $dbconn.Open()
  $dbcmd = $dbconn.CreateCommand()
  $dbcmd.CommandText = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbname.UNIT WHERE STATUS = 3'
  $rdr = $dbcmd.ExecuteReader()
  $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
  $dt.Load($rdr)
  $dbconn.Close()
  echo $dt.rows.count
  ## Returns 1
  echo $dt.rows[1]
  ## Returns nothing
  echo $dt.rows[1].column0
  ## Returns nothing







code ```
````

Comment: Why do you think the count is working?  If you have data in row 2, why does `$dt.rows.count` return 1?  It seems like it should be 2 or more.

Comment: Index in an array is zero-based, so for count equal to 1 there's no second (`[1]`) element

Comment: If $dt has rows 0 and 1, $dt.rows.count = 2.  So @astentx, are you saying that for row 1 $dt.rows[0].column0 should return something?  But the OP wants the value from row 2.

Comment: Your query always return a single row, because there's no `group by` in it and it has an aggregate function.

Comment: Ah.  Correct.  `COUNT(*)` will return 1 row.  So how does $dt exported to CSV return 2 rows?

Comment: @dougp I say that if count is equal to 1 there's no the second row it the result set. Regardless of what OP or I say/want/expect. Machine is just executing the code, it doesn't guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because index start to 0, try this:

```
$dt.rows[0]
$dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString()
```